# CSS3 Transitions in PhoneGap: Div Width issues

Tags: css, cordova, css-transitions

I am building a PhoneGap/Cordova app and have a simple code that uses http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ 
to display a div when another div is clicked.

```
<style>
#hiddendiv {
    top: -2000px;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>

<script>
$('#clickme').click(
            function() {
            //SHOW DIV
            $('#hiddendiv').transition({ y: '2100px' });
            });
</script>

<!--HTML-->
<div id="hiddendiv">
Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah Loooong piece of text
</div>

<div id="clickme">
Click Me
</div>
```

And it works fine. The issue is that I cannot scroll on my device once the #hiddendiv is displayed.

I this is partly because the page is only about 500px height (*not actually set anywhere*) whilst the #hiddendiv is about 1500px height

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your working in IOS or Android why not use Webkit transitions in css. If you set the height of body tag to 100%?

```
<style>
body {
height: 100%
}

#hiddendiv {
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -2000px);
-webkit-transition: all ease-in 3s;
}
</style>

<script>
   $('#clickme').click(
            function() {
            //SHOW DIV
            $('#hiddendiv').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, 2100px)');
            });
   </script>
```

Also it will be natively faster (at least on iOS) because its using webkit rather then jquery animate.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million. That does the trick! (for anyone else: the IOS simulator can be a bit funny - works on the device fine though which is the ultimate goal!)

Comment: If its a little jerky try adding
'-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);' to the body or div tag. That tricks iOS to processing it as a 3d element.